# Llamadas asincronas javascript y tarea asincrona .net

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

En mi trabajo un compañero hizo una afirmación, el dijo que no tenia sentido hacer un método asíncrono en [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) si en [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) estas haciendo una llamada asíncrona con [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax).

¿Cual sería la ventaja de tener una llamada asíncrona en [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) y al mismo tiempo tener un método asíncrono en [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)?

Comment: comparto la idea @rnd, la pregunta se queda abierta :) Vamo a compartir!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entiendo que cuando se refiere a asincronia en .net se refiere a `async/await` y el uso de `Task<>`

La llamada que el cliente realice no tiene que ver a como se realizara el procesamiento de la llamada. Implementar asincronia en el servidor ayudara a que los request se realicen en varios thread y puedan procesarse en paralelo.

Es verdad que si invocas mediante un ajax asincrono la UI del usuario no se bloquea, pero eso es solo una parte, cuando llega el request al servidor debes pensar en como este va a escalar el procesamiento

[Introducción a async y await en ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/magazine/dn802603.aspx)

Esta claro que si tu codigo del lado del servidor es sincrono, crear un webapi no tendra sentido que sea asincrona, la idea es que el codigo de acceso a datos, archivos, etc sea asincrono para que el servicio expuesto pueda escalar en el servidor y atender mayor numero de request.

[Why should I create async WebAPI operations instead of sync ones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26158789/why-should-i-create-async-webapi-operations-instead-of-sync-ones)

En resumen, cuando piensas en uan llamada asincrona desde ajax estas pensado en como la UI responde al usuario, cuando piensas en asincronia del lado del servidor estas evaluando como esta escala a los multiples request

Comment: Genial la respuesta, me has clarificado mucho el paronama. Ahora me surge la duda de cuando debo usar llamadas asincronas en en servidor, seria conveniente usar llamas asincronas en cada request del server?

Comment: Seria bueno implementarlas cuando accedas a recursos que pueden consumir un tiempo de procesamiento, como ser consultas a la db (en este caso segyramente necesites usar entity framework) o lectura de archivos (usando metodo async). La idea es que sea asincrono si el codigo que vas escribir dentro tambien implementa logica asincrona, de esta forma podra escalar

Answer (score 3):

**No hay ninguna relación entre un hecho y el otro.**

Empezando por que prácticamente todo proceso dentro del ordenador es asincrónico. Incluso cuando el código es sincrónico, hay algo de fondo que lo esta sincronizando.

En cuando a C#, hay varias razones para usar `async` y `await` del lado del servidor.

Cuando usas `async/await`, todo funciona en un `ThreadPool` que sincroniza todas las operaciones, sin que tengas que poner mucho código de tu parte para lograrlo.

Así que mientras un `await` espera que (por ejemplo) la base de datos termine de hacer lo suyo, el thread que empezó dicho Request se libera y esta disponible para otro trabajo. Luego cuando la base termina, otro Thread (quizá el mismo) retoma la tarea.

En definitiva, `async/await` aporta performance y escalabilidad al servicio web.